# How to create two types of users on Asp.Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

Started a project on asp.net core 3.1 and I have the following question.

I want the user when registering to chose whethere he is a user or a company.
I have no idea how to implement it so every suggestion will be helpful.
I am using .net identity.

Thank in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

So, Identity gives you an absolute load of options but don't think it has that one. Luckily you have the Claim system and so storing it in a Claim would be one option.

Or create some other data structure in your database like a UserType field, probably on your "user" table and use a selectlist with a couple of options in it to select from.

Sounds like you're quite new to development and the question is pretty broad in its nature so I would recommend doing a couple of courses in key areas, time well spent I would think.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have already setup the Identity Membership and only need help collecting additional data on a user. If this is the case please follow this blog post https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-identity-custom-user-properties/